# How much time passes in The Big Lebowski?

Tags: chronology, the-big-lebowski

In the opening scenes of *The Big Lebowski* we see the Dude writing a cheque dated 9/11/91. His bowling team, consisting of him, Walter, and Donny, is bowling for the semis.

In the closing scene, the Dude meets the Stranger at the bar, the Stranger saying he wouldn't miss the semis.

How much time passes between that? Do we have any way of knowing?

Comment: The Dude is incorrect about the year — the Big Lebowski clearly takes place between the Iraqi invasion of Kuwait (Aug 1990) and the UN coalition counter-invasion (in early 1991).  President Bush’s “this unchecked aggression will not stand” comment, which is on the TV while the Dude is in the checkout line, was given on August 5th, 1990.  So either the Dude is spacing out on what year it is, or deliberately backdating his check. (If the later, the date might be wrong too….)

Comment: Not backdating, but postdating, if he's writing a cheque for a later date. I feel another question coming on.

Comment: that's just, like, your opinion, man

Comment: Two things we know: the Dude's landlord asks him for the rent on the 9th of some month ("tomorrow's already the tenth"), and then his subsequent dance performance is on a Tuesday.