# Did the Dude postdate his check?

Tags: chronology, the-big-lebowski

> This will not stand. This will not stand, this aggression against Kuwait.
>
> — [President George H.W. Bush, 5 August 1990](https://www.margaretthatcher.org/document/110704)

In the opening scenes of *The Big Lebowski*, we see the dude walking around *Ralph's*, a convenience store, buying a pack of milk and paying with a cheque.
Behind the cashier, president George Bush sr. is seen on television, answering questions about the Iraqi invasion of Kuwait. The fragment is from 5 August 1990.
Yet the cheque the Dude writes, is dated more than a year later: 11 September 1991.

So either the Dude postdated his cheque, or the fragment was a repeat.

**Was that fragment routinely repeated, even over a year later? Or did the Dude postdate his cheque?**

I'm asking this because of [my other question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/115548/9382), about how much time passes in the film.

Comment: This is discsussed on the [IMDb goofs page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118715/goofs?item=gf2533671), but the information there reads like speculation with no source.

Comment: Considering the vast number of other chronological mistakes in the movie, including a scene with a 1997 calendar when the entire movie was supposed to take place during the Gulf War, I'd say it was merely another chronological goof.